# AWS S3 Standard upload scheme vs Browser-based uploads in node

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to understand what are the implementation differences between a standard AWS S3 upload scheme (e.g. using aws-sdk) and browser-based uploads, particularly, in node.js.

I understand that in any case, there needs to be a server that will store my AWS credentials and sign the requests to S3.

But there's a bunch of things I don't seem to understand:

- If I use a browser-based upload, I'll have an HTML form on the client side with the signature and the policy values in hidden fields that I get from my server. But if I use a standard scheme for uploading files, i.e. completely through my server, how exactly is it implemented? There's a lot of code examples on server side implementations, but what should happen on the client side? So, there will be an HTML form with `action` attribute pointing to my server's URL designated for file uploads, right? But what will actually happen? Will the file firstly get uploaded to my server's storage and then to S3? Or will it somehow use streaming or something? It really confuses me and I'd really appreciate some code example where there's both server and client side code.
- What are the pros and cons of both uploading schemes? When should I favour one approach over another (my personal use case - video uploads in a multi-account system)?

Comment: You need to decide if you want the upload to happen directly to S3 (POST) or via your server (proxied PUT). Read http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingHTTPPOST.html.